# How do I query list for any matches on item property?

Tags: c#, linq, properties

I have a `List<Tuple<int, string>>`. I want to get a `bool` indicating whether there is a match on any of the `int` values. So for example:

`{1, "Yada"}, {2, "Data"}` returns `false`
`{1, "Yada"}, {1, "Data"}` returns `true`

Can it be done?

Comment: Yes but that question involves `List<int>` and I have a `List<Tuple<int, string>>`.

Comment: It's the same premise - group by your key value and see how many groups have more then one element.

Comment: Ok cool, so thats how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done by grouping:

```
bool match = list.GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Item1, t => t).Any(group => group.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: My saviour in the c# abyss!

Answer (score 1):

Just group by that value and see if any groups have more than one item:

```
bool hasDupes =
    list.GroupBy(t => t.Item1)
        .Any(g => g.Count() > 1)
```